# Call Requests Limit

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, 0x, pancakeswap, 1inch-dex-aggregator

I made a bot swap on bsc network using 1inch 0x and para swap.. everything is great except one thing which is Call requests I can’t make call every 1 sec for more than 1 token when make 2 tokens my ip address get block , I tried to reach 0x and 1inch to ask them if there is a way to get more requests call however I get no response from all. So I’m asking you for an answer. hope to get a answer as son as possible. Thank you

Comment: That seems a limitation by the rpc provider. You could try using a third party provider or run your own node infraestructure. The bsc chain has a 3 seconds average block time, so requiring blockchain data under 3 seconds might not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

The 0x API is rate limited as described here: https://docs.0x.org/0x-swap-api/advanced-topics/rate-limiting

On that link you can request a more generous rate limiting.